# what permission should be added for external library in android

Tags: android

What permission should be added in android manifest file when we import external library in android project?

Lets guess i import one library named as "axis.jar" into my project.
I add following permission to my android project.

Still Application is force closing!!

**Thanks & Regards**
Mohammad Danish

Comment: can you post logcat error code ?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to add any permissions to include a .jar library in your Android project.

However, make sure that you place your jar inside the project/libs folder (if no "libs" folder exists in your project, create it)

Jars places in libs will get automatically included by Eclipse ADT plugin (assuming you are using Eclipse) within your Android APK so that the code within the jar is accessible at runtime.